# Обоснование статистического предположение

Tags: математика, статистика, теория, теория-вероятностей, статический-анализ

Я новичок в статистике, подскажите пожалуйста!
Если есть некоторая статистика (например сколько подков в месяц изнашивают кони разных пород). Пусть в виде таблицы она выглядит так:

```
   Кличка|Кол-во подков|Порода

1. Пегас |      5      |Вороной
2. Олимп |     25      |Вороной
3. Триумф|     25      |Вороной
4. Заря  |     16      |Орловский
5. Дунай |     15      |Орловский
6. Рейн  |      1      |Орловский
    ...    ...       ...
```

И так далее много-много строк.

С помощью какого аппарата статистики и/или теории вероятности можно обосновать утверждение например "Кони породы Вороной  изнашивают больше 10 подков значительно больше, чем конь породы Орловский"?

Я погуглил про обоснование статистических гипотез, но это кажется не про то, ведь гипотеза строится о характере распределения, а в данном примере есть только утверждение, которое необходимо обосновать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пород две?
Тогда задача традиционна. Сводится к проверке гипотезы о равенстве средних значений (медиан) двух выборок. Для ее решения есть несколько вариантов в зависимости от тех или иных ограничений - например, нормальности закона распределения, равенстве дисперсий и пр.
Наиболее используемые методы анализа - по Т-критерию Стьюдента (в случае выполнения указанных ограничений) либо метод Уилкоксона-Манна-Уитни - в случае не выполнения их.

Эти гипотезы позволяют ответить на вопрос - "кони породы А изнашивают больше подков, чем кони породы Б с достоверностью ХХ%". Если же вас интересует подтверждение именно утверждения "ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО больше", то все осложняется, вы переходите в область теории нечетких множеств и для начала требуется выяснить, что-же такое "значительно". Но я склоняюсь к мысли, что это была неточность вашей формулировки, а изначально задача стоит так, как я ее описал в первом абзаце.

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое за ответ! Да, породы всего две. А, если не трудно, подскажите книгу, которую стоит прочитать, что изучить эту область знаний?

Comment: Нет проблем, только я не знаю Вашей начальной подготовки. Поэтому не обижайтесь - начну с суперэлементарного. Есть такая книжка Савельев В.«Статистика и котики»: АСТ; Москва; 2018 -  несмотря на полную элементарность, там все понятно, мне кажется - даже ребенку. Чуть посложнее - С. Гланц. "Медико-биологическая статистика". И еще чуть сложнее - С. Бослаф. "Статистика для всех". Ну а далее - уже более специальная литература. Надо будет - подскажу.